# Move constructor for a class with const member variables. This appears to work

Tags: c++, move-semantics

I am trying to figure out the behaviour of the implicitly generated move constructor when I have constant member variables. The below compiles up with no warnings (when using -Wall -Wextra under g++)

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

struct myclass
{
                const int num;
                const std::vector<int> vec;

                // Delete copy constructors
                myclass(const  myclass&)        = delete;
                myclass( myclass&)              = delete;
                // Default move constructor
                myclass( myclass&&)             = default;
};

int main()
{
        myclass A = {1, {2}};

        std::cout << "Before  A: " << &A.vec[0]
                << "\nBefore  A[0]: " << A.vec[0]
                << "\nBefore  A int: " << A.num;

        myclass otherA = std::move(A);

        std::cout << "\n\nAfter moving:\nOrig  A: " << &A.vec[0]
                << "\nOrig  A[0]: " << A.vec[0]
                << "\nOrig  A int: " << A.num;

        std::cout << "\n\nOther A: " << &otherA.vec[0]
                << "\nOther A[0]: " << otherA.vec[0]
                << "\nOther A int: " << otherA.num << std::endl;

        return 0;
}
```

when I compile and run I get

```
Before  A: 0x55fd59295eb0
Before  A[0]: 2
Before  A int: 1

After moving:
Orig  A: 0x55fd59295eb0
Orig  A[0]: 2
Orig  A int: 1

Other A: 0x55fd592962e0
Other A[0]: 2
Other A int: 1
```

This works fine. Note that if I change the vector to be a non-const member, then it appears to do a regular move on it (i.e. it does a regular std::move on the member and then attempting to access A[0] seg faults and &otherA[0] is the same as the original &A[0])

Why does it appear to "work" though? I would have assumed it would not work as it would not be able to move the constant variables.
Is this undefined behaviour which happens to work under g++? I specified c++17 standard with compiling.

Comment: A move of a constant is a copy and fulfills all requirements that moving stipulates.

Comment: Thanks @NathanOliver. That appears to be what is happening. Is that defined by the standard (i.e. it is perfectly legal and portable code to do so?)

Comment: Yes this is legal and portable.  The main thing you need to consider is that having const members means your class is no longer assignable by default.  You either have to write your own assignment operators or just not allow the class to be assignable.  That can/will dictate what you can do with the object.

Comment: Note that the `const` member variables themselves were not *moved*, they were *copied*.  Not sure if that is important for your use case or context.

Answer (score 1):

You can add output to the members special member functions to better see what happens:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

struct mymember {
    int value;
    mymember(int x) : value(x) {};
    mymember(const mymember&) { std::cout << "cpy ctr\n";}
    mymember(mymember&&) { std::cout << "move ctr\n";}
    mymember& operator=(const mymember&) { std::cout << "cpy assign\n"; return *this;}
    mymember& operator=(mymember&&) { std::cout << "move assign\n"; return *this;}
    operator int() const { return value;}
};

struct myclass {
    const mymember num;
    // Delete copy constructors
    myclass(const  myclass&)        = delete;
    myclass( myclass&)              = delete;
    // Default move constructor
    myclass( myclass&&)             = default;
};

int main() {
    myclass A = {{42}};
    myclass otherA = std::move(A);
}
```

[Output](https://godbolt.org/z/ah6Ynf893):

```
cpy ctr
```

As mentioned in comments, for something that cannot be moved (for example because it is `const`) a move falls back to a copy. That is expected and well defined behavior.

Consider that there are many legacy types from before c++11 that cannot be moved, but they have to interoperate with code that uses move semantics.

You can experiment with above code: remove the `const` from the member, [the member will be moved](https://godbolt.org/z/ocMqqGKG5). Then remove the move constructor, [the member will be copied](https://godbolt.org/z/e1ofGE74h).